# css text animation looping

Tags: html, css, vue.js

How to use animation do loop infinitely which will keep sliding & repeating non-stop and i wanna make it full screen loop but it keeps breaking when reach hello5 .... what i want is i wanna create 3 rows and looping the same item from my items array . Not sure which css is wrong now

Example result i want:

[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="testi-bg">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="h1 mt-5 testi-h1">Looping</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tech-container" >
      <div class="tech-box-wrapper"  >
        <div
          v-for="(item, index) in combinedItems"
          :key="index"
          class="tech-box"
        >
          {{ item }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      "hello1",
     "hello2",
      "hello3",
      "hello4",
      "hello5",
     
    ],
  }),

  methods: {},


  computed: {
    combinedItems() {
      const duplicatedItems = [...this.items, ...this.items ]; 
      return duplicatedItems;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

my css i am using marquee animation

```
<style scoped>
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.tech-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tech-box-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  animation: marquee 14s infinite linear;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); 
}

.tech-box {
  background: #ffffff1a;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a "clone" set of items to the right of the original set of items within each `.tech-box-wrapper`. This helps give the seamless loop effect. We translate left until the first set of items is completely out of view then the animation resets, making it look seamless.

We set `width: max-content` on `.tech-box-wrapper` so that the width of it is the width of all the elements inside, so that the `translateX(-50%)` will be one width of the set of items, again for the looping illusion.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  components: {},
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      "hello1",
     "hello2",
      "hello3",
      "hello4",
      "hello5",
     
    ],
  }),

  methods: {},
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

.tech-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tech-box-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  animation: marquee 14s infinite linear;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  width: max-content;
}

.tech-box {
  background: #ffffff1a;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.13/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-+zQHTEdBz6qFFCqtL7esgT75IdGLn/CKCHA5sIBDark8kw5ffzoqrmTSXd4V94DBcsF1ND0qExmWbPcPZ7ebSA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="testi-bg">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="h1 mt-5 testi-h1">Looping</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tech-container" >
      <div class="tech-box-wrapper" v-for="i in 2">
        <template v-for="i in 2">
          <div
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            class="tech-box"
          >
            {{ item }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```